# Logic in sentence : tree representation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining, deep-learning, text-mining

I have sentences telling me to who a shop is opened to:

- "cats, dogs or birds" (1)
- "young dogs with collar" (2)
- "old cats or yellow birds" (3) etc...

I would like to design an algorithm that will change this sentences to a tree representation of the logic in it:

- (1) = (cat) or ((dog) or (bird))
- (2) = (young) and (dog) and (collar)
- (3) = ((cat) and (old)) or ((bird) and (yellow))

What do you think will work the best? LSTM maybe? How can I have this representation as a result?

Comment: first look at this:https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/automatically-converting-natural-language-to-first-order-logic I think this can be helpful too https://deepmind.com/research/publications/programmable-agents/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syntaxnet](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/05/announcing-syntaxnet-worlds-most.html) parser could surely help you in parsing the sentences and in tree represenation.

If you plan on solving using RNNs, I believe [Tree LSTM](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm) will be a better choice than LSTM, as it also preserves dependency information. 
[Full paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00075).

Use `Tree LSTM`, if you need a vector embedding for the whole sentence. For use cases like classification, sentiment analysis. It works and there is a good probability that the vector could have all the information but you may not be certain and thats why its still a black box. But, if your use case is a clear representation of tree structure and logic among the terms (which you wanted), better go with parsers like `Syntaxnet` and try rule-based models for the use case mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about Tree LSTM ! For my problem, Syntaxnet is a good approach indeed, I'll try it !